# How to change the navigation of the back button android C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

So I've been developing my first app and everything is going great except for the back button.

When you press back it does the back animation but it lands on the same Activity then it closes.
I want it so when you press back it goes to the main Activity(the first one(the start menu))
in my code you cans ee that I tried adding the noHistory = true but that didnt work either.
here is what it looks like
[image]

Here is the code for (QUESTION 2) which you can see if giving me the issue

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace TestingFixes
{
    [Activity(Label = "firstQ", NoHistory =true)]
    public class firstQ : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.firstQDesign); // Change This



            Button easyBtn3 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.oopBtn); //Change This
            easyBtn3.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { //Change This



                easyBtn3.Click += delegate { //Change This
                    StartActivity(typeof(easySecondQ)); //Change This
                    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.easysecondQDesign); //Change This

                    //Would I maybe connect the text here to an int?


    };


            };






        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the mainACtivity (start menu)

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace TestingFixes
{
    [Activity(Label = "TestingFixes", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


            Button easyBtn2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.easyBtn);
            easyBtn2.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {



                easyBtn2.Click += delegate {
                    StartActivity(typeof(firstQ));
                    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.firstQDesign);

                    //Would I maybe connect the text here to an int?


                };


            };

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize onBackPressed() method of Activity

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    if(condition)
        super.onBackPressed(); // this close app
    else
      // your code to open MainActivity
    }
```

Comment: Might be because im really tierd, but where do I add that? https://i.gyazo.com/828eb89423dd4572562f878ca5e84513.png

Comment: inside your Activity class. where you added onCreate() method.